# Почему newtonsoft.jsonconvert так десириализует объект (c#)?

Tags: c#, json, newtonsoft.json

Не могу понять почему jsonConvert так работает.

Есть класс данных:

```
    internal class SomeData
    {
        public string code { get; }
        public string message { get; }

        public SomeData(byte code, string message)
        {
            this.code = code.ToString();
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
```

И есть Main:

```
        public static void Main()
        {
            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Vector2(1, 3));

            SomeData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeData>(jsonString);
            Console.WriteLine(data.message + "<---");
        }
```

Вывод при запуске:

```
<---
```

Если запустить всё это дело, то все будет нормально, хотя должна же быть ошибка. Почему так происходит?
И тем более, если дать `{}` json строку, то он всё равно не даст ошибку.

Comment: Какую вы ошибку ожидаете? То, что вы вектор пытаетесь в `SomeData` засунуть, типа разные типы, ошибка присвоения, или что? Если да, то JSON это текст, не более, не менее. В JSON есть значения, по которым ищется свойство, если этого свойства в классе нет, оно пропускается, а если есть, то заносится значение в класс. Также и наоборот, если свойство есть в классе, а в JSON нет, то класс будет иметь значение по умолчанию у данного свойства. Другими словами, должно быть строгое соответствие имен свойств, а не типа сериализуемых/десериализуемых объектов.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(jsonString);` - что выведет?

Comment: С чего бы должна быть ошибка? Десериализатор не находит свойства с нужными именами, не может задать им значения, они остаются пустыми.

Comment: Ранее я пытался делать тоже самое, но не с SomeData а с другими классами и иногда возникали ошибки JsonSerializationException. Вот я и решил, что тут тоже будет ошибка... Не понимал как работает это дело. Спасибо всем)